# XCode Storyboard merging

Tags: merge, xcode4.2, xcode-storyboard

Is there a way to merge XCode 4.2 Storyboard files?

I'm working with another developer on an iPhone project and all my attempts at merging changes into a storyboard file have met with failure and after which Xcode is no longer able to load the storyboard. Consequently I have to do an svn revert and then redo my modifications.

Comment: as far as I know there is no way. and that is the argument to keep using XIB files when working in a team.

Comment: A way to help with storyboards is to have multiple ones. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575702/segue-to-another-storyboard

Comment: These might be helpful: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297701/using-multiple-storyboards-in-ios> <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756117/include-an-ios-storyboard-project-into-another-one> <http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1316064> This one is also relevant to your question but it doesn't look like it has a definitive answer: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705160/sharing-scene-between-multiple-storyboard-files-iphone-vs-ipad>

Answer (score 1):

Here's the only tool I've ever come across which lets you merge storyboards:

https://github.com/marcinolawski/StoryboardMerge

Comment: NB: I tried to undelete the author's own answer which gave this tool too, but I need two other mods approval. It's been almost a year and they haven't stepped-in, so I'm glad I simply re-posted the answer. This process is not good - don't credit me for the answer.

Comment: I believe that some people don't like us revealing the flaws in StackOverflow, and the poor quality moderation done by some people, within the answer to a question. So I moved it to the comment instead.