# Integrate an xcode project into another xcode project and link the two storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have an xcode project which is integrated into a new xcode project. Now the new xcode project has a storyboard where am adding view controllers that should be linked to the added xcode project. In simple words from the new app ( from new xcode project) i have to access the old app (the older xcode project) screens. Is it possible?

I had referred [Adding xcode Project into another xcode project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370518/xcode-4-2-how-include-one-project-into-another-one)
and this link [connecting two storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756117/include-an-ios-storyboard-project-into-another-one)

Could anyone suggest any ideas.

Comment: What's wrong with the solution at the second link you provided (connecting two storyboards)? You should only need to load the storyboard that contains the view/controller you want to instantiate, instantiate it, and then present/push it.

Comment: @rickerbh i tried it by changing the storyboard names as Main (which is the new project) and another as main_mage(the old project) and connected as guided but while running app it got terminated saying main_mage not found.