# Pushing a navigation controller is not supported

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

In my MainStoryBoard I want to push a viewController to the detailView but I get this error:

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'

I set the identifier 'JSA' ID for the viewController on the storyboard.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        SWSJSAViewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"JSA"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to push a view controller, not another navigation controller. If you really want to display another navigation controller, you need to present it, not push it.

Comment: Thanks a lot ready, the error is gone, but it goes to the tableViewController, I want it on the detail, Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817305/pushing-a-navigation-controller-is-not-supported-performing-segues/23102975#23102975
(I've got an answer that worked for me, but maybe one of the others will do the trick for you.)

Comment: Like maddy said, this raises an exception with "Pushing a navigation controller is not supported".  You have to     [self presentViewController: viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: also make sure you hv entered storyboard identifier in viewcontroller, not in navigationcontroller

Comment: Navigation Controller can't contain Navigation Controller again. It should be only one.

Answer (score 51):

Like [rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) said in the comments you are trying to push a navigation controller.

Navigation controllers should be presented (via presentViewController or they can be added as a childViewController) and ViewControllers should be pushed.

Answer (score 39):

When you talk about **pushing** Navigation Controller, it is ***most likely*** that you want to present it.

1. ***Presenting* UINavigationController**

This is the most common way and this is what you want to do in most cases. `UINavigationController` cannot be pushed, it can only be presented with a new root View Controller.

```
MyViewController* vc = [[MyViewController alloc]
      initWithNibName:@"MyController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *myNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: vc];

[self presentViewController:myNav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

What you do here, is firstly create a `UINavigationController` and then set necessary `UIViewController` as its root controller.

---

2. ***Pushing* UINavigationController**

If you have a hierarchy of ViewControllers and you need to push view controller that contains navigation controller within, steps are:

**1) Push ViewController, containing `UINavigationController`.**

To *push* `UINavigationController`, first create a subclass of `UIViewController`, which will be a wrapper-/container- class for your `UINavigationController` and its content.

```
ContainerViewController* vc = [[ContainerViewController alloc] init];
```

**2) Adding UINavigationController as a child view controller**

In `viewDidLoad` of your container (that you have just instantiated) simply add something like this:

**Objective-C**

```
UINavigationController* myNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: rootViewController];
[myNav willMoveToParentViewController:self];

myNav.view.frame = self.view.frame;  //Set a frame or constraints
[self.view addSubview:myNav.view];
[self addChildViewController: myNav];
[myNav didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

**Swift 4.2+**

```
let childNavigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
childNavigation.willMove(toParent: self)
addChild(childNavigation)
childNavigation.view.frame = view.frame
view.addSubview(childNavigation.view)
childNavigation.didMove(toParent: self)
```

What you do here is basically instantiate your navigation controller and add it as a child controller to your wrapper. That's it. You have successfully *pushed* your UINavigationController.

Comment: This is a much more comprehensive answer which addresses the need to support hierarchical navigation controllers without modal presentation. Should be the top answer.

Comment: There is a problem with UINavigationItem in embedded navigation controller. You can't add bar buttons easily. Problem is that the original navigation item from parent is used so you have to access it like `parent.navigationItem...`. And that's very bad from the point of reusability of view controllers.

Comment: @Deny Yes, there's an issue. But you can handle it by hiding parent navbar and managing inherent navigationItem. From UI perspective, it would look equal.

Comment: @Hexfire It's not so easy. If you hide the parent navbar you can't use the system back button. Therefore you have to add the custom back button in child navbar and that's ugly as calling the navigation item through its parent.