# How to correctly push to another Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have some VC which should push to **ANOTHER** Navigation Controller.
If I do just

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someID") as someVC, animated: true)
```

this is not working. I can add

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someID") as someVC, animated: true)
    }
```

So it works but as I know it's not correctly way to use it. What I should use? `presentViewController` ?

Comment: Where are you calling that code? In viewWillAppear?

Comment: Try to put your code in a method, and call it after 0.01f delay

Comment: Why if with delay I still should use dispatch_async?

Comment: What happens if you put it in viewDidAppear?

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should push only UIViewController subclasses inside a navigation controller.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757072/pushing-a-navigation-controller-is-not-supported) might help!

Comment: as I see there recommend use presenetViewController

Comment: yes, you could use "presentViewController" to present another View Controller, previously it was called "presentModalViewController", and it allowed you to present a view controller "modally".

Comment: just If I use "presentViewController" next VC work strange: without navigationBar etc.

Comment: I'm sorry but the question you asked gives not enough information to understand your problem.

Comment: I've added presentViewControl to NavigationController which I need and this works without dispatch_async! But still one problem: it works without animation even I set animation: true