# Pushing a navigation controller is not supported - since Xcode 6.2 update

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, segue

Hope someone can help me here,

I have used a segue to popover a tableView onto the main view with no problems up until now.

After the Xcode 6.2 update I get 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported', I am not setting it as a push, I am setting it as a popover.

I have done a lot of work to this project only to be put back 2 months because of this.

Please help.

PS, I am writing it in swift.

Comment: Is this storyboards or xib? If you're presenting by code can you supply your code

Comment: So, I have some issue. After update Xcode to version 6.2, all popover segues are changed to push. I guess is Xcode's bug, because I was change it back to popover segue but in app is used push segue. Can anybody give a suggestion instead use Xcode version 6.1.1?

Comment: Update!!

I have reported this to Apple via bug reporting and have been told that it is a duplicate bug report!?! 

1. If this is a duplicate, how do I view the original.

2. If it's been reported more than once, WHY ISN'T IT FIXED IN 6.3?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757072/pushing-a-navigation-controller-is-not-supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some problem and I guess that is Xcode's bug. My solution is to download and use Xcode 6.1.1 instead 6.2.

P.S. In my case this problem happened just when segue is assigned to UIBarButtonItem. So, and after I'm relaunching Xcode popover segue is changed back to push segue.

P.P.S. I'm writing in Objective-c

Comment: That's exactly what I done, needed to change every instance where Xcode 6.2 had changed popover to push.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same thing... had to uninstall xCode 6.2 and reinstall 6.1.1  I wonder if this is still an issue in xCode 6.3? I haven't updated to yosemite just yet.

*have not enough reps to comment so I'm posting this as an answer.