# Push UINavigationController programmatically. iOS9

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios9

I want to display a navigation controller programmatically. This code works perfect on iOS 8, but on iOS 9 it doesn't work.

```
var vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view_controller_id") as! UIViewController;
var nc = UINavigationController()
        nc.setViewControllers([vc], animated: false)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(nc, animated: true)
```

After that I am getting this error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller
>   is not supported'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757072/pushing-a-navigation-controller-is-not-supported

Answer (score 0):

You can't push a navigation controller to another navigation controller. You will have to show your navigation view controller with viewcontrollers modally or just push your view controllers to the active navigation controller.

Comment: @SlavikVoloshyn can you provide some sample code? It shouldn't work