# Cannot push back to view controller embed in Navigation Controller

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I have created ViewController A (a.k.a vcA) and vcB embed in Navigation View Controller ,mapping child view controller in storyboard as classes.m

When I try to construct this redirect of view controller A->B->A  , or to create vcA from vcB  , by using :

```
A : 
    PairViewController * sliderVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PairViewController"];
    sliderVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:sliderVC animated:NO completion:nil];
    sliderVC.view.backgroundColor =  [UIColor clearColor];


B :     ViewController *destinationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
     [destinationController setBle:_ble];
            [destinationController setLeDevice:selectedDevice];

            destinationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

     [self presentViewController:destinationController animated:NO completion: nil] ;
```

The new A is created without any navigation bar appeared.

When I use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:nil];
```

The xCode said for the exception ;

```
Cannot call pushNavigationItem:animated: directly on a UINavigationBar managed by a controller.'
```

Would you please tell me the way to create vcA from vcB , with my custom navigation bar keeping intact , not missing ?

In A I try to construct the navigation bar in this method but navigation bar turns nil if creating vcA from vcB

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{

    navigationBar=  [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {


    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

    navigationBar =  self.navigationController.navigationBar;
    [navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                            [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                            [UIFont fontWithName:@"TitilliumText22L-Medium" size:22.0], NSFontAttributeName,
                                            nil] ];

    UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"FPV Control"];

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 20)];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //    UIBarButtonItem *buttonItemA = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

    UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                                                       target:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)];

    [leftBarButtonItem setCustomView:button];
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem;

    UIButton *buttonA = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 20)];
    [buttonA setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rc_logo.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *buttonItemB = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonA];
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItemB;
    [navigationBar pushNavigationItem:navigationItem animated:NO];


    NSLog(@" navigaytion item  :  %@" ,  navigationItem);
    NSLog(@" navigaytion bar  :  %@" ,  navigationBar);
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is the exact viewcontroller flow you are going? eg : aViewcontroller > (model) bViewController > (push) aViewController

Comment: aViewcontroller  : presentViewController to bViewcontroller

bViewcontroller  : presentViewController to aViewcontroller          //  [self presentViewController:destinationController animated:NO completion: nil] ;

Comment: only  models , no pushes

Comment: So are you creating this custom NavigationBar in every ViewController viewWillAppear??

Comment: Yes , not much difference even in every ViewController viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So present your ViewController with NavigationController as below.

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = 
    [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];

//now present this navigation controller modally 
[self presentViewController:navigationController
                   animated:NO
                   completion:nil];
```

Comment: I have an empty UINavigationController set  on Storyboard (without mapping to the implementation class ). It turns to showing this error 

Cannot call pushNavigationItem:animated: directly on a UINavigationBar managed by a controller.'

Comment: Then map your storyboard UINavigationController to here or create it pragmatically as above

Comment: Do you mean mapping my UINavigationController to my ViewControllerA   or create the new one mapping?

Comment: It saids I cannot push push a navigation controller to another navigation controller. What should I do then ? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33044758/push-uinavigationcontroller-programmatically-ios9

Comment: From bViewController when presenting aViewController [self.navigationController  presentViewController:navigationController
                   animated:NO
                   completion:nil];

Comment: I have just set as above and set Storyboard id in navigation controller , it turns 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'

Could you please tell me What is the next step ?

Comment: I have to set the storyboard id in embedding navigation controller in xcode storybaord but it turns to

 [UINavigationController setCheckSumByte:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...

Comment: HOw to pass data among view controllers afterwards ?

Comment: And I am trying to use same navigation bar for all child view controllers

Comment: Go through this. If you can't understand then ask http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers