# swrevealviewcontroller navigation item and bar button missing

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

hello I have implemented `SWRevealViewController` in my swift app. The problem I am having is If I set **SWRevealViewController** as my initial ViewController all works fine. But If I launch this controller through code

```
 let nav : UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("swrevealviewcontroller") as UIViewController)
 self.navigationController?.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

the navigation Title and barButtonIcon Disappears which is in my case is a hamburger menu icon.

SWRevealViewController is connected to the HomeViewController. and I am initiating SWRevealViewController when user clicks the login Button.

If you need more information regarding the storyboard screenshot let me know. I'll upload here.

Updated: 
storyboard

[image]

Comment: if you are using `presentViewController` , the `presentViewController` does not embedded with `UINavigationController `.if you want `UInavigation COntroller` in `presentViewController` , implement in customize

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik then should I use push?

Comment: ya if you using `push`, the `UINavigationController` will come , the reason `push` is embedded with `UINavigationController`.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have done this  let nav : UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("swrevealviewcontroller") as UIViewController)
                    
                  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nav, animated: true)

error comes which is 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'

Comment: connect your current viewcontroller embed with `UINavigationController`, then it works,

Comment: see this link for error bro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757072/pushing-a-navigation-controller-is-not-supported

Comment: you mean I have to embed the swrevealViewcontroller with the navigation controller on the storyboard? am I right ?

Comment: no I have tried this also then menu doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103479/discussion-between-hellosheikh-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`navigation controller's` navigation bar will only show up for view controllers that are contained by that `navigation controller`.  Here, you're `presenting` a modal view.  It's not contained by the `navigation controller`.

If you want the navigation bar to continue to appear:

- If it's purely a matter of style, put a navigation bar on the modal scene you're presenting in the interface builder.
- If you need to modally present a view that should be contained in a navigation controller, then you need to present a navigation controller--not a view controller.
- Finally, if the view you're presenting is intended to be part of the navigation controller's navigation stack, then you need to present it with a push, not a modal segue.

**Update**

Do like simple ,

[image]

and call the perform segue as

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"main" sender:self];
```

Comment: navigation Bar is appearing but navigation Items on the navigation bar is not appearing

Comment: are you asking me to upload storyboard screen or mobile app screen ?

Comment: which viewcontroller you want to navigate

Comment: @I haven't attached the login screen controller because that is separate and not connected to anything. But login controller has navigationcontroller embeded. so When I click the login button in logincontroller I want to go the homescreencontroller which is you can see on the image

Comment: Did you understand ?

Comment: AWESOME.. THANK YOU... Can I have your skype ?

Comment: ya sure but most of the time I am not used the skype , take my ID , karthik.saral@gmail.com. welcome bro, bye

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik One last thing I want to ask.. are you there?

Comment: okay It works fine somehow.. But In My Main Screen which is before the loginform screen where there is a button of login and register. I am checking on that controller that if user is alreadylogged in or not. If Logged in then I am launching the controller with my same old code that is in my question and same problem comes. what should I do about that ?

Comment: haha ha , swl is complicated for this concept, ok we go for based on your condition , create the one NSUSerdefault and save when login is successful, then if you terminate the app and reopen time on that `loginform` page on viewdidload chek teh userdefault value is equal or not ,if it is eqaul follow the update answer , else do nothing ..

Comment: yes I am using nsuserdefault already. I am actually asking the navigation problem. if client is already logged in I am doing this

  let nav : UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("swrevealviewcontroller") as UIViewController)
            
            self.navigationController?.presentViewController(nav, animated: false, completion: nil)

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by pointing Navigation Controller first and Tab Bar Controller second. Please, see the picture below.
Hope this help!..Thanks...
[image]