# How I can move another storyboard with navigation bar?

Tags: swift, segue, navigationbar

When first play the app(In StoryboardA), app check the user's before data, and I want to change the screen according to the content.
(StoryboardB, StoryboardC, ...)

So I check the user data from server and if user data exists,

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Category", bundle: nil)
let nextViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
```

But it occurs error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'
```

How I can change the screen from StoryboardA to another Storyboard(StoryboardB, StoryboardC, ...) with navigationbar?

Comment: you either need to present a new navigation controller or set the rootViewController on the AppDelegate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pushing a navigation controller is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757072/pushing-a-navigation-controller-is-not-supported)

Comment: The error it's absolutely right. You can not push a navigationViewController. you must push viewController instead

Comment: @EneaDume In change another storyboard, I can't back before storyboard?