# Xcode 7 ibtool error: Deploying Storyboard References to iOS 8.0 requires that your storyboards do not share any view controller identifiers

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have an iOS app targeting iOS 8 and 9 which I'm in the process of upgrading to use Storyboard References instead of links through code. I've gradually converted more and more bits over, when suddenly I started getting this compiler error:

> : error: Deploying Storyboard References to iOS 8.0 requires that your storyboards do not share any view controller identifiers. A.storyboard and Z.storyboard both contain a view controller with identifier "ZNavigationController".

`Z.storyboard` absolutely contains `ZNavigationController`, it's supposed to be there, however `A.storyboard` assuredly does not contain any such navigation controller. I've opened the .storyboard file in a text editor and verified that there is no mention of `ZNavigationController`.

To give some more context:

- `A.storyboard` has a reference to `B.storyboard`, and it has a manual segue from one of the viewControllers in `A`
- `B.storyboard` has a reference to `Z.storyboard` - it gets there via a manual segue from one of the viewControllers in `B`

Running XCode Version 7.0 (7A218) which is the GM seed build

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a bit more digging and it turns out that even though `A.storyboard` didn't have anything with that storyboard ID, there was a controller in `B.storyboard` and also in `Z.storyboard` which both had the Storyboard ID of `ZNavigationController`. 
The one in `B.storyboard` had an incorrect ID which I removed.

Looks like Xcode is misattributing the (correct) error to `A.storyboard` instead of `B`

Answer (score 10):

Found the problem (I'm using Xcode 7.1.1).

After using Product --> Refactor to storyboard, it create a storyboard references with a storyboard ID same than the reference ID (attributes & identity inspector).

This is a bug, storyboard ID should be nil and only the reference ID should be filled.

[image]

**Update #1 :**
When creating multiple storyboard reference using "Refactor to storyboard", it create the same object ID which cause this error too.

**Update #2 :**
Just don't use the "Refactor to storyboard" feature if you target iOS 8. It create multiple doublons with objectId which cause an error like :

```
/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */ : error: Deploying Storyboard References to iOS 8.0 requires that your storyboards do not share any view controller identifiers. Category.storyboard and Home.storyboard both contain a view controller with identifier "UIViewController-BX3-FJ-k0T".
```

Comment: I found same problem, but i didn't found same reference id :(

Deploying Storyboard References to iOS 8.0 requires that your storyboards do not share any view controller identifiers. Main.storyboard and UserProfile.storyboard both contain a view controller with identifier "UIViewController-jus-ow-Yti"


i'm using xcode 8, i search for every storyboard file, but still missing

Answer (score 3):

First you need to find which Reference is doubled
**UIViewController-5kv-Ul-Bah** - it was my error

Press cmd + 3 and input id (**5kv-Ul-Bah**) without "**UIViewController-**" find doubled references

You should see something like this

[image]

In my case it is InvitationDetails.storyboard and Location.storyboard

You have 2 options:

**Option 1**: Remove **Storyboard Reference** from storyboard and add another one (do this with my other instructions https://stackoverflow.com/a/33753164/2493555)

**Option 2**: Open new created storyboard as source code

[image]

then find our id and change it to another like **"5kv-Ul-Bahxx"** (I add xx postfix) but you need to be sure that string "5kv-Ul-Bahxx" is not exist in project (by pressing cmd + 3 and find)

[image]

Comment: As an alternative to manually editing the file you can also create a copy of the effected view controller and then delete the old one.  You need to reconnect any segues as well.  The copied version will get a new Object ID automatically which should resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

- Click on the offending storyboard reference
- Open the identity inspector
- Delete the "Storyboard ID".

As far as I can tell, there's no need to reference a reference, and this seems to be the thing it's complaining about. When you use 'refactor to storyboard', it leaves the storyboard id in the reference.