# Two xcode projects in one workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, workspace

Can somebody tell me how can two swift main storyboards from to separate xcode projects living in a workspace can segue each other.  I am using xcode 7

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Segue to another storyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575702/segue-to-another-storyboard)

Comment: You can’t segue to a storyboard that is not in a project. If it’s not in the project, it won’t be included in the resources for that app.

Comment: Gary, I thought XCODE 7 can do it... Is anybody know how can I segue in XCODE 7?  Thank you