# Xcode hangs/unexpectedly quit while opening large Main.storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I got chance for working on a huge iOS project, for Views `Storyboards` are used in this project. There is advantage of using Storyboard that everything in a single file, but now that `Main.storyboard` is grown tremendously over the period of time, whenever I open `Main.storyboard` in `Xcode` for any updates it takes minutes, and `Xcode` gets hang or `Quits unexpectedly`.

What should I do to take on this problem, is there any design to split down large `Storyboard` file?

Comment: You can use multiple storyboard for your purpose. Split by function, feature or your flow of your app.Read some related link
[When](http://www.newventuresoftware.com/blog/organizing-xcode-projects-using-multiple-storyboards) [How](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115697/ios-9-storyboards-tutorial-whats-new-in-storyboards)

Answer (score 0):

You can use storyboard linking like you need to put some of your controllers in another story board and you also can access controller like this ([Segue to another storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575702/segue-to-another-storyboard))