# Present view controller from another storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

index.swift

```
func didReceiveNewSession(_ session: QBRTCSession, userInfo: [String : String]? = nil) {
    print("Receive")
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let goController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "call") as! call
    self.present(goController, animated: true)
}
```

If I'm in `index.swift` and I receive session, print `Receive` for me and go to `call.swift`.

But if after load `index.swift` I go to `page.swift`, if receive session, print `Receive` but don't go to `call.swift` and stay on `page.swift`.

I want if I'm anywhere after `present`, go to `call.swift`

Comment: It's difficult to follow exactly what you are asking here, can you elaborate more? You're just trying to programmatically open up a VC from a different storyboard then the VC you are currently viewing?

Comment: @JustinMiller, Yes. i write codes in index VC, but i'm not in index VC. if i call index codes, don't go to another VC

Answer (score 2):

- Open your first Storyboard and create a Storyboard Reference 
  [image]
- Enter the name of your second Storyboard in the "Storyboard" property and the Reference ID of the destination ViewController in the "Reference ID" property of your newly crated reference. (Reference ID is equivalent to Storyboard ID of the destination ViewController)

  [image]
- Create a segue from your source ViewController to the newly created Storyboard Reference. Make sure the segue has an Identifier.
- In your code perform the segue like this

.

```
func didReceiveNewSession(_ session: QBRTCSession, userInfo: [String : String]? = nil) {
    print("Receive")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)
}
```

Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33753164/7990095

Comment: You mean Xcode project file? I'm sorry I can't send the project due to copyright reasons. Just ask if you can't follow the steps and I'll try to explain further.