# Can Xcode 4.4 merge the storyboard files changed by two developers now?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard

The storyboard files in iPhone has always been a nightmare to developers -- It has no way to when two developers made changed to the same file!

This seems to be a very serious bug! I would like to know whether this bug has been fixed in Xcode 4.4? Can anyone give me a walk around?

Thanks

Similar questions were asked for previous version of Xcode:

4.3:
[Xcode 4.3 how to merge storyboard changes from two developers using SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434581/xcode-4-3-how-to-merge-storyboard-changes-from-two-developers-using-svn)

4.2:
[XCode Storyboard merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393214/xcode-storyboard-merging)

Comment: This is something that may be covered by NDA, you'll have better luck asking on Apple's non-public forum for the members of their developer program.

Comment: 4.4 is out now so it's ok :-)

Answer (score 1):

A storyboard file is (and always has been?) XML; you can often merge this using normal text merge tools.