# How to merge 2 storyboards with conflicts in git?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, storyboard

While working on a project in git there was conflict in storyboard while I was trying to merge two branches. Is there any way to merge two conflicted storyboards using Git.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393214/xcode-storyboard-merging

Comment: right click conflicted story board , Open as Source code , Remove conflicts as you remove in .m and .h files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can grab this tool and use it:

Read all about it, how to install and configure in the official project page:
https://github.com/marcinolawski/StoryboardMerge

[image]