# iPhone IOS5 Storyboard, how to load a UIViewController with a custom .xib file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, interface-builder, storyboard

I have some UIViewControllers from my old iOS4 project, they are using .xib, created in interface builder.

My new project, built for iOS5, uses storyboards.

**I'm trying to add a UIViewController to the storyboard, but have it use a custom XIB that I already have**. I've set the controller's identity in the indentity inspector (in interface builder), but am not sure **how to ask that controller to load a custom .xib.**

Any help is appreciated!

PS. Up to date I was able to get around this by creating a "wrapper" class for the storyboard purposes, and have that class have another UIViewController. But this kinda defeats the whole point of a storyboard.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could copy the contents of the xib into the storyboard and then instantiate it using:

```
- (id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

after setting the identifier on it. If you need the instance of the storyboard you can get it this way:

```
[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Isn't it simpler to just copy .xib contents to his main storyboard file?

Comment: Yeah that's what I was telling him to do. Note that you can also get the storyboard from any UIViewController from the storyboard property.

Comment: After messing with wrappers and the order of viewDidLoad kind of crap, I'm happy to just copy the interface over and manually hook it up, even though this is what I was hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Mike K's answer is false.

While mixing XIBs and Storyboards doesn't really solve Alex's problem, it *is* quite possible to do within the same project.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8516479/1309238 re: loading a second storyboard.

I'm not sure if including a "Main Storyboard" in your Target Summary is advisable if you plan to do this, but if you've loaded a XIB instead of a storyboard to begin with, you can modify the code linked above to load the storyboard after the XIB.

I'm not sure if you can jump into the middle of a storyboard from a XIB, which may have been what Mike meant.

Answer (score -12):

You cannot mix xibs and storyboards in your project -- it's one of the other, I'm afraid.

Comment: This is false. You can have xibs and storyboards.