# ToolBar back button is not working

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem

Iam doing one project using storyboard ,in one viewcontroller i have a button.When i clicked that it will move to next viewcontroller but its a separate xib file.  Now i tried to add aback button to that xib file So i can move back to my storyboard but its not working form me ?

I tried following code for moving from xib to storyboard viewcontroller

```
viewcontrollerOne *list= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
[self presentModalViewController:list animated:YES];
```

please let me know the reason why its not working?

Comment: if you want to add it as programmetically then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704686/how-to-add-bar-buttons-in-a-uitoolbar/14704726#14704726

Comment: Please Read My question.

Comment: @Naveen, Please check have you given identifier name in storyboard for that class correctly, if yes please also try this method instead of presentModalViewController, since it is deprecated: [self presentViewController:list animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: @RamuPasupuleti : its not working i gor this error  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <viewcontroller2: 0x123550b0>.'

Comment: @Naveen, This error occur while you are trying to present a view controller that has not instantiated. Please check class names and identifier names.

Comment: @Naveen, viewcontrollerOne is a part of stoardboard or not. If not,it is a separate xib file..above code couldn't work..choose this..                                                  viewcontrollerOne *list = [[viewcontrollerOne alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewcontrollerOne" bundle:nil];  list.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

[self presentModalViewController:list animated:YES];  Try this, and let me know

Comment: @RamuPasupuleti  ViewcontrollerOne is a part of story board   but viewControllerTwp is a separate xib

Comment: @Naveen, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705815/iphone-ios5-storyboard-how-to-load-a-uiviewcontroller-with-a-custom-xib-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work when you want to move from an xib to a viewcontroller in Storyboard,Its working for me.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try changing your project to UINavigationController and then in the storyboard you can link the views