# Linking two Storyboards from IB side

Tags: iphone, storyboard, xcode5, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a Main `Storyboard` which initial `ViewController` is a `UITabBarController`, one of the tabbed controllers branches in plenty controllers, so I've moved all of them to a whole different `Storyboard`.

So far I've set a custom `UINavigationController` into the appropriate tab in my *MainStoryboard*, and in its `viewDidLoad` method I programmatically set its root `UIViewController` loading it from the new `Storyboard`.

It works, but my question is:

**Is there anyway to achieve this directly from `Interface builder`, with a `segue` that somehow links both `Storyboards`?**

Comment: So far I know there is no way to link it up using IB. You would have to programmatically do it. If you find out a way ,do let me know. I will also search onto it.

Comment: Thanks @walle84, I don't think it's possible neither, just wondering if anyone knew a workaround. Anyway, I'll stick to programmatic way then.

Comment: okay..  @ssantos dude you could also vote my answer !

Answer (score 0):

maybe I am too late but I find this approach very useful, try it out:
http://robsprogramknowledge.blogspot.com/2012/06/linking-storyboard.html

Accepted answer:
[What is the best practice when using UIStoryboards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965749/what-is-the-best-practice-when-using-uistoryboards)

It allows you to stay on IB level and preserve modularity of your code and UI. It also allows connecting multiple storyboards in IB in a way that you can preserve visual feeling of the app flow.