# iOS 7 - Setting the current view controller as root of navigation

Tags: ios7, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I need to set the view controller of the home screen as the the root of the navigation controller, no matter how the user reaches it (push/show or custom segue)

The following code put in the viewDidLoad of a view controller seems to have no effect with iOS 7:

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[self]];
```

The navigation stack does not change at all.

Have you ever experienced any similar issue?

Thanks,
DAN

Answer (score 0):

Create global reference of navigation controller in App Delegate and then with the reference of appDelegate you can change you rootView controller anywhere just type below code :

```
[appDelegate.navigaitonController initWithRootViewController:viewController];
```

Note: Here viewController is new viewcontroller reference which you want to set as root of navigation controller .

Comment: UINavigationController has no setRootViewController method.
Calling [appDelegate.navigationController setViewControllers:@[self]] in the viewDidLoad of the view controller has no effect as [self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[self]]

Comment: @DAN you can use initWithRootViewController at the place of setRootViewController . initWithRootViewController is instance method of navigation controller .

Comment: if still not working then let me know again with chunk of your code . I ,ll provide you solution for that .

Comment: Doing:
appDelegate.navigationController = self.navigationController;
[appDelegate.navigationController initWithRootViewController:self];
results in: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported

Comment: you can not set view controller as a root in same class . Let you have A view controller . You cant set A as a root view controller in viewDidLoad . It will give you exception

Answer (score 0):

Call your UIViewController method from app delegate like this..try it out.

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
ViewController* pp = [[ViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController* nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pp];
self.window.rootViewController = nav; or [self.window setrootviewcontroller=nav];
[self.window addSubview:[nav view]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: I cannot open my view controller like that as it can be reached from different flows of more than one storyboard

Comment: @DAN check this link it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297701/using-multiple-storyboards-in-ios

Comment: Thanks for your hint but my problem is not how to link storyboards, I'm trying to understand why the method setViewControllers does not work

Comment: @DAN may be your NavigationController has not been initialized and loaded properly .Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Only one line to make your current viewController as rootviewcontroller

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController = self;
```

Comment: This changes the root view controller of the entire app but doesn't affect the navigation controller stack